# Python "root.after(1000, my_test)". It cycle every second but twice

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a situation with my script, hopefully you can help me to find the root cause.

In my test script below, I use the function *"root.after(1000, update_timeText)"* to execute the counter *"update_timeText"* in theory every 1000 milliseconds (every second).

This function also update a GUI every second displaying 1, 2, 3, 4, .... The first time I execute works perfect and every second the "update_timeText" is executed every second only one time GUI properly update every second 1, 2, 3, 4, .....

However, if I stop the clock and re-start the counter, GUI update every second but displaying 1, 3, 5, 7..... every second. The "Funny" situation is that in the reality the cycle ran twice. If I print the variable *timer [0]*, this variable shows 1, 2, 3, 4.... but due to function *"root.after(1000, update_timeText)"* updated the GUI every second it display 1, 3, 5, 7.

Now, if I stop again the clock and restart, now the GUI will display 1, 4, 7, 11, 14.... but the variable *timer [0]* in the reality is counting 1,2,3,4,5... but really fast.

My code below; hopefully someone can help me out to solve this problem

Thanks for stopping by.

```
    def update_timeText():
        global temp
        global degree_sign
        global temp_b
        global temp_c
        if (state):
            global timer
            timer [0] +=1
            if (timer[0] >= 60): ## timer [0] Seconds     
                timer[1] += 1
                timer[0]  = 0
            if (timer[1] >= 60):  ## timer [1] Minutes
                timer[2] += 1
                timer[1]  = 0
            if (timer[2] == 24):  ## timer [2] Hours    
                timer[2]  = 0
            timeString = pattern.format(timer[2], timer[1], timer[0])
            timeText.configure(text=timeString)
        root.after(1000, update_timeText)
    def update_temp():
        global timer
        global loga
        global temp
        global degree_sign
        global temp_b
        global temp_c
        global temp_alter
        if (timer[0] == 1):
            temp = a.read_holding_registers(17415, 1)
            temp_alter = a.read_holding_registers(1031, 1)
            temp_a = str(temp)
            temp_b = temp_a.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
            temp_c = temp_b[:2]+'.'+temp_b[2:]
            if (temp_alter >= [40]):
                degree_sign= u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
                Label(text=(str(temp_c)) + degree_sign + "C",fg = "red", font=("Arial", 12)).place(x=210,y=443)
            if (temp_alter <= [39]):
                degree_sign= u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
                Label(text=(str(temp_c)) + degree_sign + "C",fg = "green", font=("Arial", 12)).place(x=210,y=443)
        if (timer[0] == 10 or timer[0] == 20 or timer[0] == 30 or timer[0] == 40 or timer[0] == 50 or timer[0] == 60):
            loga.write("Time Stamp : Hours " +(str(timer[2]))+" ; Minutes "+(str(timer[1]))+" ; Seconds "+(str(timer[0]))+"\n")
            loga.write("Temp Stamp : "+(temp_c) + degree_sign + "C"                             "\n")
        if (timer[1] == 1):
            end_time1 = datetime.now()
            endd1 =(end_time1.strftime("%A %d %b %y, %H:%M"))
            def pause():
                global state
                state = False
                global timer
                timer = [0, 0, 0, 0]
            pause()
            process = "PASSED" 
            Label(text="PASSED      ", fg = "green", font=("Arial", 12)).place(x=210,y=543)
            loga.write("==============================================\n")
            loga.write("My Company.                                   \n")
            loga.write("Assy PN   #: 00000-00 Rev. A                  \n")
            loga.write("Serial    #: N/A                              \n")
            loga.write("Start Date: "+str(startt)+"                   \n")
            loga.write("End Date  : "+str(endd1)+"                    \n")
            loga.write("Station   : TEST                              \n")
            loga.write("Status    : "+str(process)+"                  \n")
            loga.write("==============================================\n")
            loga.close() ##to close logfile
            write = a.write_single_register(8245, 3)
            time.sleep(0.050)
            write = a.write_single_register(7668, 3)
            time.sleep(0.050)
            connect_btna.config(state = NORMAL)
            start_btna.config(state = DISABLED)
            abort_btna.config(state = DISABLED)
        root.after(1000, update_temp)
    def start():
        global state
        state = True  
        ##Starting Set Profile
        write = a.write_single_register(8245, 1)
        ##Lock Door Enabled
        Label(text = "DOOR  LOCKED...     ",fg = "green", font=("Arial", 12)).place(x=210,y=343)
    start()
if status == "":
    messagebox.showinfo('Process App 1.00', "An Error has occurred, Please, restart the app. Click OK to continue")
    write = a.write_single_register(8245, 3)
    time.sleep(0.050)
    write = a.write_single_register(7668, 3)
    time.sleep(0.050)
    loga.write("An Error has accurred.....\n")
    write = a.close()
    sys.exit()
    root.destroy()
    quit()
if status == "Fail":
    messagebox.showinfo('Process App 0.00', "An Error has occurred, Please, restart the app. Click OK to continue")
    root.destroy()
    quit() 
def pause():
    global state
    state = False
def reset():
    global timer
    timer = [0, 0, 0]
    timeText.configure(text='00:00:00')
def exist():
    root.destroy()
timer = [0, 0, 0]
pattern = '{0:02d}'+" h "+' {1:02d}'+" m "+' {2:02d}'+" s "
timeText = tk.Label(text="00:00:00", font=("Tahoma", 12))
timeText.pack()
timeText.place_configure(x=210,y=393)
update_temp()
update_timeText()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have apparently called `update_timeText()` more than once, elsewhere in the program - each one is going to result in its own once-per-second series of repetitions. "Don't do that" is really all that can be said without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper I have the function *update_timeText()* outside of *def update_timeText()* but that's it. I can share my code if you want

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Hi @ReblochonMasque I have add a few more code, please let me know if this helps. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @jasonharper Just to let you know that I have found the root acuse of my problem. The Function *"root.after(1000, update_timeText)"* it was out of the loop, so, I move right under "timeText.configure(text=timeString)" and that solve my problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

After analice my script, I have discovered that the belong function it was not properly nested, this is what I had

```
        timeString = pattern.format(timer[2], timer[1], timer[0])
        timeText.configure(text=timeString)
    root.after(1000, update_timeText)
```

after I properly nest the *root.after(1000, update_timeText)* my test script is working and running as a champ.

```
        timeString = pattern.format(timer[2], timer[1], timer[0])
        timeText.configure(text=timeString)
        root.after(1000, update_timeText)
```

Thanks to all, 
F Casian